# How to select a line from a MySQL text field

Tags: mysql, preg-match

Say I have a mysql table which contains two columns, one is a job number, and the other contains the stderr of the respective job:

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| job      | int(11) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| jerrors  | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The text contains newline characters. 
I would like to select from jerrors only the lines containing a given word, i.e. something like

```
(\n.*word*.*\n)
```

How would I construct such query? If I do

```
SELECT job, jerrors FROM mytable WHERE jerrors LIKE "%No such file%";
```

then I get the whole text in the column.

Here's a sample text

```
Error in <TCling::RegisterModule>: cannot find dictionary module A2Dict_rdict.pcm
Error in <TCling::RegisterModule>: cannot find dictionary module A1Dict_rdict.pcm
Error in <TCling::RegisterModule>: cannot find dictionary module SpectraDict_rdict.pcm
PedestalT0 File : conf/A2-roT0.job1685_0-run1685_2.dat: No such file or directory
[A1DataDecoder] WARNING: 12 Slots for 20 pedestals! Using '16' for last 19 pedestals ...
Error in <TInterpreter::TCling::AutoLoad>: failure loading library libMathMore.so for ROOT::Math::GSMIntegrator
```

Comment: difficult because mysql regular expressions are geared towards pattern matching rather than string manipulation. Easier to do this in your programming language.

Comment: Hi, did you tried using trim to get ur output. If you can give few sample of jerrors it would be helpful to answer ur question correctly. Might be i am not interpreting ur question correctly

Comment: It may be easier to split up the error message by lines and store each line in a separate record. This way you do not have to write complex logic to retrieve the matching line from a field.

Comment: Yes, these are options indeed, but I was hoping for something elegant doable within the query.

Comment: I ended up adding the text in the DB line by line. Thank, Shadow.